# Doctrine attributes for 3 linked entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to make a website that list albums, each albums have tracks, and in order to handle various artists albums, each track is made by an artist.
I'm new with symfony and I'm fighting with doctrine to find the best way to handle those 3 entities (album, track and artist).

- Album (id, title, release_date, cover, etc...)
- Track (id, id_album, id_artist, title, position, duration)
- Artist (id, name, country, photo,...)

I was thinking about doing one-to-many/many-to-one relations or many-to-many with attributes, but I'm really not sure anymore what's the best way to link those 3 entities in doctrine.

At the end, I would like to make a homepage that looks like that :

```
[album_cover] 
"album title"
   artist

[album_cover]
"album title"
artist1, artist2
```

So from the album entity I need to get all the artists from all the album's tracks, I don't know yet how to do that.

So far I've done that, but I'm really not sure if it's the best way (with AlbumArtist = Track):

```
/**
* Album
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\AlbumRepository")
*/
class Album
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AlbumArtist", mappedBy="album", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $albumArtists;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="text")
 */
private $title;
```

---

```
/**
* Artist
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ArtistRepository")
*/
class Artist
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AlbumArtist", mappedBy="artist", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $albumArtists;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text")
 */
private $name;
```

---

```
/**
* AlbumArtist
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\AlbumArtistRepository")
*/
class AlbumArtist
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album", inversedBy="albumArtists")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="album_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $album;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Artist", inversedBy="albumArtists")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="artist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $artist;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="text")
 */
private $title;
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Your sequence is a bit strange in my opinion.

Lets make a few statements in human language:

> An **Album** exist out of multiple tracks.
>
> One **Track** exist out of one **Song**.
>
> One **Song** can be composed by one or more **Artist**s.

I use the entity Song because a song can be placed in multiple Albums and on a different track-number.

Gives us the those relations:

> Album - oneToMany - Tracks (an Album have multiple tracks)
>
> Tracks - ManyToOne - Song (a Song can be placed on multiple tracks)
>
> Song - oneToMany - Artists (some songs are made by multiple artists)

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your answer. Your statement make sense, but a single song wrote by different artists is rare in my case (it's for a chiptune music database and I never saw any track done by more than one artist), so I don't want to complexify the logic more than it is. So my model is An Album exist out of mutiple tracks and each track is composed by one and only one Artist. Thanks